# Remove empty strings from TStringList

Tags: delphi, vcl

Is there any build-in function in Delphi to remove all strings from a `TStringList` which are empty?

How to loop through the list to remove these items?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To answer your first question, there is no built in function for that.  Looping manually is easy. This should do it:

```
for I := mylist.count - 1 downto 0 do
begin
  if Trim(mylist[I]) = '' then
    mylist.Delete(I);
end;
```

Note that the for loop must traverse the list in reverse starting from Count-1 down to 0 for this to work.

The use of `Trim()` is optional, depending on whether you want to remove strings that contain just whitespace or not. Changing the `if` statement to `if mylist[I] = '' then` will remove only completely empty strings.

Here is a full routine showing the code in action:

```
procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  mylist: TStringList;
begin
  mylist := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // Add some random stuff to the string list
    for I := 0 to 100 do
      mylist.Add(StringOfChar('y', Random(10)));
    // Clear out the items that are empty
    for I := mylist.count - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      if Trim(mylist[I]) = '' then
        mylist.Delete(I);
    end;
    // Show the remaining items with numbers in a list box
    for I := 0 to mylist.count - 1 do
      ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(I)+' '+mylist[I]);
  finally
    mylist.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The reverse traversal is crucial (+1). Maybe the answer should better say a word about this instead of telling details about an "optional" `Trim` part.

Answer (score -1):

Another way that eliminates the overhead that Trim and Delete incur..should work with any TStringList compatible object.

```
S := Memo1.Lines.Text;

// trim the trailing whitespace
While S[Length(S)] In [#10, #13] Do
  System.Delete(S, Length(S), 1);

// then do the rest
For I := Length(S) DownTo 1 Do
  If (S[I] = #13) And (S[I-1] = #10) Then
    System.Delete(S, I, 2);
```

Comment: Your solution introduces a lot of **overhead for understanding** it. But it misses to apply the text to `Memo1.Lines.Text` after the normalization process. BTW this is compatible with `TStrings` not only `TStringList`, try to check the type of `Memo1.Lines.Text`.